# What's the difference between bind() and bindProperty() in PolymerJS?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

Seems like `bind()` is part of the Web Components spec, which Polymer extends for various reasons [with `Node.bind()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/node_bind.html).

Here's [docs on `bindProperty()`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/87b3815812aaa9f956f044e74d43460b1babee5f/src/instance/properties.js#L180). Is this simply the internal implementation/polyfill for `bind()`? And thus should developers thus be using `bind()` rather than `bindProperty()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the source code of `bind` - [line 56](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/instance/mdv.js#L56)(full snippet below). There the `bind` function calls the internal `bindProperty` function. All that `bind` is doing on top of `bindProperty` is ensuring that the given property exists.

```
bind: function(name, observable, oneTime) {
var property = this.propertyForAttribute(name);
if (!property) {
  // TODO(sjmiles): this mixin method must use the special form
  // of `super` installed by `mixinMethod` in declaration/prototype.js
  return this.mixinSuper(arguments);
} else {
  // use n-way Polymer binding
  var observer = this.bindProperty(property, observable, oneTime);
  // NOTE: reflecting binding information is typically required only for
  // tooling. It has a performance cost so it's opt-in in Node.bind.
  if (Platform.enableBindingsReflection && observer) {
    observer.path = observable.path_;
    this._recordBinding(property, observer);
  }
  if (this.reflect[property]) {
    this.reflectPropertyToAttribute(property);
  }
  return observer;
}
```

So, you could use `bindProperty`, but I would not recommend it unless you can ensure the existence of the property, which you want to bind.